# (node:21484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: manager.push is not a function

Tags: node.js

I keep receiving the following error for each role that select in my Team Profile Generator:

(node:21484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: manager.push is not a function
at C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Team Profile Generator\GOTEAMGO\index.js:48:29
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

```
then(({ fullname, id, email, role }) => {
        if (role === "Manager") {
            let manager = "";
            return inquirer
                .prompt([{
                    type: 'text',
                    name: 'office',
                    message: " What is the Office Number?"
                }])
                .then(({ office }) => {
                    manager.push(new Manager(fullname, id, email, office))
                    teammates.push(manager);
                    cardhtml(teammates)
                    html();
                })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `manager` variable is a string. And in javascript, there is no `push` function defined for strings. Could you try changing,

```js
let manager = "";
```

to

```js
let manager = [];
```